# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unterminated string. Expected delimiter: ". Path 'data.3681.sanitizedDescription', line 1, position 65535.'

Tags: mysql, json, vb.net

My application would parse straight from the source and worked fine. However, since the original source of information was not always available, I decided to store it into a MySQL database. I store the JSON string in a table and then extract it later. However, I am now receiving the titled error message. I believe somehow, the string is being truncated but I do not understand why. Below is my code. My question: How do I stop the titled error?

to write the string to the database

```
Dim strUpdate As String = rrm.returnLeagueItems()
If String.Compare(strUpdate, strError) = 0 Then
    rm.updateDynamicQuery("rgo_manager", {"manager", "region"}, {strUpdate, rrm.strRegion}, {"manager_name"}, {"items"})
End If
```

To pull the JSON request

```
Private Function returnJSONRequest(ByVal strWebAddress As String) As String
    Try
        Dim strReturnArray As String() = {}
        Dim wrWebResponse As WebResponse
        Dim wrWebRequest As WebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(strWebAddress)
        wrWebResponse = wrWebRequest.GetResponse()
        Dim srStreamReader As New StreamReader(wrWebResponse.GetResponseStream)
        Dim strReturn As String = srStreamReader.ReadToEnd()
        wrWebResponse.Dispose()
        srStreamReader.Dispose()
        Console.WriteLine("Success: " + strWebAddress)
        Return strReturn
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("Failure: " + strWebAddress)
        Return "IAmError"
    End Try
End Function
```

JSON object

```
Public Class RGOLeagueItemManager
    Inherits RGOLeagueObjectManager
    Public Property league_container As LeagueItemContainer

    Public Sub New()
        league_container = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of LeagueContainer)(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(rm.returnDBQueryAsDataTable("SELECT manager FROM rgo_manager WHERE manager_name = 'items';").Rows(0).Item(0)))
    End Sub
End Class
```

rm is simply my remote manager to access my database.
rrm is the class that contains all the JSON requests to the server where all the web addresses are stored but only the returnJSONRequest is important. I would highly prefer not to have to "chunk" the data either. If I could load all the information, I should be able to do so with MySQL. The field is a BLOB.

Edit: Here is the rm code since it appears the string is being truncated upon entry into the database but is the full size in the query parameter.

```
Public Sub updateDynamicQuery(ByVal strTable As String, ByVal strSetParameters As String(), ByVal strSetValues As String(), ByVal strWhereParameters As String(), ByVal strWhereValues As String())
    Dim strQuery As String = "UPDATE " + strTable + " SET "
    Dim intSetCount As Integer = strSetParameters.Length() - 1
    For i = 0 To intSetCount
        strQuery += strSetParameters(i) + " = @setparameter" + i.ToString()
        If i < intSetCount Then
            strQuery += ", "
        End If
    Next
    strQuery += returnWhereClause(strWhereParameters)
    strQuery += ";"
    Console.WriteLine(strQuery)
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(strQuery, league_champion)
    Dim intParameterCount As Integer = strWhereParameters.Length() - 1
    For k = 0 To intParameterCount
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter" + k.ToString, strWhereValues(k))
        Console.WriteLine(strWhereValues(k))
    Next
    For i = 0 To intSetCount
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@setparameter" + i.ToString, strSetValues(i))
        Console.WriteLine(strSetValues(i))
    Next
    executeQuery(cmd)
End Sub

Public Sub executeQuery(ByVal cmd As MySqlCommand)
    Try
        connection.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Console.WriteLine("Query success: " + cmd.CommandText)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("Query failed: " + cmd.CommandText + "//" + ex.Message)
    End Try
    connection.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: So the JSON **text** is invalid. Look at it.

Comment: It worked fine before I started sending it to a database first...

Comment: Okay, I checked the string being placed into MySQL and and the string being called from the same place. The JSON string is fine going into the query string but does not stay intact when I view it in the database. Is BLOB not big enough and is there something bigger? I had a MySQL tag but someone removed it... pretty sure the question is mostly about MySQL the more I keep hunting around for no answer.

Comment: Would also love to know why I have to have a -1... I already looked at the JSON text but if you want to downvote me because it's too confusing for you, that's awkward. I am legitimately having a problem but people are too busy removing tags that I need to replace instead of helping answer the question.

Comment: Not my downvote, but the problem I said in my first comment is still 100% valid. *Look at the JSON, and perhaps include it in question: it is invalid.* Work back from there: what about the JSON is invalid, and how did such flaw get introduced?

Comment: Yea, the "how did such flaw get introduced" was my problem. I did not know which portion of the code would even possibly truncate the data. Obviously, now I know that it was the data field itself. I did not realize how big the data I was working with was in relation to being much to small for a BLOB type. School leaves a lot of information out it seems.

Comment: That it does.. it takes time and practice to develop techniques to quickly isolate "real world" problems.